# How to access a child if the parent of that child has a parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a problem with my actionscript 3.0

I can't access a child (let's call it child A), where child A has a parent Sprite (called sprite B). And Sprite B has a parent C (sprite).

For example:

```
var prBoard:Sprite = new Sprite();
prBoard.name="p";
var spMatrix:Sprite = new Sprite();
spMatrix.name="s";
var tf:TextField = new TextField();

            tf.width = 30;
            tf.height = 20;
            tf.name = "r";
            tf.text= "27";

this.addChild(prBoard);
prBoard.addChild(spMatrix);
spMatrix.addChild(tf);
```

The question is how to access textField tf?

Comment: I have no idea, never use actionscript. I only edited your grammar and spelling, I have no answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
trace((((getChildByName("p") as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildByName("s") as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildByName("r") as TextField).text); //27
```

Comment: i dont understand , what do you mean ship it? sorry i am a newbie and not good in english

Comment: He means if it works, it's good to go. Remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.